# How to push an object into a constructor?

Tags: javascript

So... I've been trying this for hours and hours... I just can't seem to get it right.
Would really appreciate some help with this exercise.

function createClassPerson() {

// Create a Class to construct and object type Person

// Constructor must get:

// name (string) , Age (integer) , hobbies (array de strings) , friends (object array),

addFriend(nombre, edad) {

// method addFriend receives a string "name" and an INT for age, an object must be added:

// { name: name, age: age} to the friends array in the Person.

// this must not return anything.

```
class Person {
    constructor(name, age, hobbies, friends) {
      this.name = name,
      this.age = age,
      this.hobbies = hobbies,
      this.friends = friends
    };
}


var julian = new Person ("Julian", 24,["Airplanes", "Running"],[{name: "James", age: 25}, {name: "Reginald", age: 21,}]);


function addFriend(friendName, age) {
Person.friends.push(
    {
    name: friendName,
    age: age,
    }
    );
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `julian.friends.push` instead of `Person.friends.push`…!?

Comment: `Person` is the object name, not an instance. If `julian` has a new friend, then you can do `julian.friends.push(newFriend)`

Comment: And that `addFriend` should be part of the class, not a separate function, no? And then it’s `this.friends.push`.

Answer (score 1):

`addFriend` is meant to be method of class `Person`, so it should be inside it, and you need to use `this.friends.push`.

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name, age, hobbies, friends) {
    this.name = name,
      this.age = age,
      this.hobbies = hobbies,
      this.friends = friends
  };

  addFriend(friendName, age) {
    this.friends.push({
      name: friendName,
      age: age,
    });
  };
}


var julian = new Person("Julian", 24, ["Airplanes", "Running"], [{
  name: "James",
  age: 25
}, {
  name: "Reginald",
  age: 21,
}]);


julian.addFriend("Jack", 24);
console.log(julian.friends)
```